# unable select unique values from a query

Tags: mysql

I want to select the name of a field on separate table, however I can only do this once. Cname1 will work , Cname2 will not. The problem is I would like a unique categoryChild name for m.categoryChildID2 but the only way I know how to reference this is with c.categoryChild BUT this is already in use with the m.categoryChildID1.

I know I can redo my table but I prefer not to if this is possible?

```
select c.categoryChild as cname1,c.categoryChild as cname2 
  FROM categoryChild as c, members as m 
 WHERE m.memberID=50 
   AND m.categoryChildID1=4 
   AND m.categoryChildID1=c.categoryChildID 
   AND m.categoryChildID2=5  m.categoryChildID2=c.categoryChildID
```

Thanks
Brian

Comment: not sure what you want to do but you can add 'DISTINCT(val)' to your query.

Comment: I have two fields that store ids of another table, problem is I can only get a unique value on the first one. It is a join on two tables I just am not sure how to get the second one unique, I tried an alias but this won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join categoryChild table twice

```
SELECT c1.categoryChild as cname1,c2.categoryChild as cname2 
FROM members AS m,
JOIN categoryChild AS c1 ON(m.categoryChildID1 = c1.categoryChildID)
JOIN categoryChild AS c2 ON(m.categoryChildID2 = c2.categoryChildID)
WHERE m.memberID=50
```